# Make link's text wrap not links themselves wrap?

Tags: css

I have links in a list which im using to make tabs as part of a responsive design.

When there is sufficient width the tabs line up as I want them to. However at smaller widths the last tab wraps onto the next line, but instead I want the text within the link itself to wrap.

I cant solve this by setting the max-width to be 33% as the number of tabs will vary per page so my CSS solution needs to work for different numbers of tabs.

[image]

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="current">Tab 1 stuff</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="">Tab 2 stuff</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Tab 3 stuff</a></li>
</ul>

ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
a {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  max-width: 33%;s
}
ul {  
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. The code you've posted seems to do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/bhCK7/.

Comment: @j08691 As the OP explained if there are more (or less) tabs it doesn't work anymore because of the `max-width:33%;` see here : http://jsfiddle.net/bhCK7/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using `display:table;` and `display:table-cell`

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MXtzX/6/)**

CSS:

```
ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul {
    width: 20%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display:table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
     background: green;
}
a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
}
```

I also changed the background color from the `<a>` tag to the `<li>` tag so there is no white space between the links.

**EDIT**

Ok the solution so that the links only use necessary width when the container is wide enough is to wrap the `<ul>` in a `div` and set the width on that div.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MXtzX/16/)**

Comment: increase the width of ul and see what happens

Comment: The issue with that fiddle is the tabs always take up the full width. This is different from the first example in the image in my question, where they only take up the necessary width.

Comment: @jdln I updated my answer to fit your requirements. (I also added a new fiddle)